# Sharing URL to Facebook, Twitter and email in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, email, twitter, sharing

Is there anything similar to getsharekit.com for Android? It allows to share URL's to social networking sites. Is there anything similar to this or do I need to code separately for facebook, Twitter and email?

Comment: Somewhat better answers for each case can be found in these questions: [Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent),  [Twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application), [email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent) (include the URL in email body using `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`).

Comment: This is my solution which is working fine just for sharing URL on Facebook, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29529335/513413

Answer (score 89):

I don't know if that's what you mean but you can use the Android built-in sharing menu...

You can share a URL to Facebook, Twitter, Gmail and more (as long as the apps are installed on your device) using Intents:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.url.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
```

If the app you want to share to is not installed on the user's device, for example - facebook, then you'll have to use Facebook SDK.

If you want your Activity to handle text data shared from other apps as well, you can add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".ShareLink">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am looking for a solution without using the installed apps.

Comment: thank you , i have changed from text/html to text/plain and this worked fine ,in addition to adding intent filter section to the activity

Comment: There's no reason to add that to the manifest. It will work fine with just the Java snippet.

Comment: @Jarett yeah, I know... it's from 2010, I was young :) updated. Thanks

Answer (score 47):

You can use also **ShareCompat** class from support library.

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setChooserTitle("Share URL")
    .setText("http://www.url.com")
    .startChooser();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ShareCompat

Comment: Now just use androidx https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ShareCompat but implementation is the same

Answer (score 6):

For facebook you can use `

> https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=website_url&t=titleOfThePost

website url could be any thing refereing to any resource for example if you want to get an image from internet and sharung it on your wall .

hope this would help

Answer (score 4):

// for URL

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.codeofaninja.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
```

// for image

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
// setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
share.setType("image/*");

// Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
// directory
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/myImage.png";

File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this...

```
private void shareTextUrl() {
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<source url>");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share text to..."));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, you can add more apps if you wish by just adding package names. This code also sorts the applications according to their names.

```
    List<Intent> targetShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    if (!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Have package");
        for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
            String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Log.i("Package Name", packageName);

            if (packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") || packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana")
                    || packageName.contains("com.whatsapp") || packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.plus")
                    || packageName.contains("com.google.android.talk") || packageName.contains("com.slack")
                    || packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm") || packageName.contains("com.facebook.orca")
                    || packageName.contains("com.yahoo.mobile") || packageName.contains("com.skype.raider")
                    || packageName.contains("com.android.mms")|| packageName.contains("com.linkedin.android")
                    || packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.messaging")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                intent.putExtra("AppName", resInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://website.com/");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_text));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                targetShareIntents.add(intent);
            }
        }
        if (!targetShareIntents.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.sort(targetShareIntents, new Comparator<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Intent o1, Intent o2) {
                    return o1.getStringExtra("AppName").compareTo(o2.getStringExtra("AppName"));
                }
            });
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No app to share.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

For me this works just fine:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,
    Uri.parse("http://...")),"Share URL"));// share url is on your own
```

Comment: Not working : error "no apps can perform this action"

Comment: reason it give no apps can perform this action is that no mimetype has been specified. App filter SEND action on type. If you do not specify it (text/plain) no app will intercept that intent