# Android and Facebook share intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I'm developing an Android app and am interested to know how you can update the app user's status from within the app using Android's share intents.

Having looked through Facebook's SDK it appears that this is easy enough to do, however I'm keen to allow the user to do it via the regular Share Intent pop up window? seen here:

[image: pop up]

I have tried the usual share intent code, however this no longer appears to work for Facebook.

```
public void invokeShare(Activity activity, String quote, String credit) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.share_subject));
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Example text");    

    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, activity.getString(R.string.share_title)));
}
```

UPDATE:
Having done more digging, it looks as though it's a bug with Facebook's app that has yet to be resolved! ([facebook bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16728)) For the mean time it looks like I'm just going to have to put up with the negative "Sharing doesn't work!!!" reviews. Cheers Facebook :*(

Comment: been broken for about a year now with multiple revisions I don't understand why they won't fix it!!

Comment: Still broken. I am starting to think they do not fix it on purpose to make you use their stupid facebook sdk.

Comment: The above share code snippet will work with the current android app (v1.9.0, release date april 20th, 2012). an arbitrary EXTRA_TEXT still won't show up, BUT the facebook app will accept any url. a share text will have to be entered by the user within the facebook app.

Comment: Ugh, it appears that Facebook has now formally responded that they don't consider the behavior broken and will not be changing it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Comment: So no fix or workaround at least? We have to live with the empty message? :/

Comment: Unfortunately the only fix or workaround is to integrate their SDK into your app.

Comment: Users have to type the content by hand: "please note that pre-filling the message parameter with suggested content which the user can edit is also a policy violation" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGz48L0m5nc

Comment: check this URL [direct share Facebook image in intent android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155890/android-share-custom-link-via-facebook/54254357#54254357) work for Android all version

Answer (score 98, accepted):

> The Facebook application does not handle either the `EXTRA_SUBJECT` or `EXTRA_TEXT` fields.

Here is bug link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Thanks @billynomates:

> The thing is, if you put a URL in the `EXTRA_TEXT` field, it *does*
>   work. It's like they're intentionally stripping out any text.

Comment: The thing is, if you put a URL in the EXTRA_TEXT field, it *does* work. It's like their intentionally stripping out any text.

Comment: It's really dumb that this still works on iOS (at the time of writing), but doesn't work on Android.

Comment: Only links can be shared on facebook with share intent.

Comment: Users have to type the content by hand: 
"please note that pre-filling the message parameter with suggested content which the user can edit is also a policy violation"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGz48L0m5nc

Comment: @PeterK.  did you found a way to send the text on facebook ?

Comment: use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759057/share-score-on-facebook-android

Comment: https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-remove-the-facebook-android-sharing-intent

Answer (score 117):

Apparently Facebook no longer (as of 2014) allows you to customise the sharing screen, no matter if you are just opening [sharer.php URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547088/how-do-i-customize-facebooks-sharer-php) or using Android intents in more specialised ways. See for example these answers:

- ["Sharer.php no longer allows you to customize."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21086232/56285)
- ["You need to use Facebook Android SDK or Easy Facebook Android SDK to share."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919693/56285)

Anyway, using plain Intents, **you *can* still share a URL, but not any default text with it**, as [billynomates commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/#comment23436287_14496338). (Also, if you have no URL to share, just launching Facebook app with empty "Write Post" (i.e. status update) dialog is equally easy; use the code below but leave out `EXTRA_TEXT`.)

Here's the best solution I've found that does *not* involve using any Facebook SDKs.

This code **opens the official Facebook app directly** if it's installed, and otherwise falls back to opening sharer.php in a browser. (Most of the other solutions in this question bring up [**a huge "Complete action using…" dialog**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCOSA.png) which isn't optimal at all!)

```
String urlToShare = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Foo bar"); // NB: has no effect!
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);

// See if official Facebook app is found
boolean facebookAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
        facebookAppFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

// As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
if (!facebookAppFound) {
    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
}

startActivity(intent);
```

(Regarding the [`com.facebook.katana`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) package name, see [MatheusJardimB's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent/21189010?noredirect=1#comment35112922_21189010).)

The result looks like this on my Nexus 7 (Android 4.4) with Facebook app installed:

[image]

Comment: "com.facebook.katana" is the package name for Facebook app and "com.facebook.orca" is for FB Messenger app. You may change to the proper pckg you want. If you don't specify one, the first found will be used (not good)

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I updated the answer. Turns out Facebook has released other apps too ([Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.home) and [Pages Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.pages.app)) that would also match the `com.facebook` prefix.

Comment: helow... if i want to fill post edittext then how to work with facebook.

Comment: how to set text as well with url ?

Comment: You can't (as mentioned in bold near the very start). Please just read the answer.

Comment: Brilliant fallback!

Comment: great solution, is there any way I can specify subject text for 'Write Something' area?

Comment: Note that the Facebook SDK now offers automatic native-app fallback in its sharing SDK:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Answer (score 17):

**The usual way**

The usual way to create what you're asking for, is to simply do the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The status update text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Dialog title text"));
```

This works without any issues for me.

**The alternative way (maybe)**

The potential problem with doing this, is that you're also allowing the message to be sent via e-mail, SMS, etc. The following code is something I'm using in an application, that allows the user to send me an e-mail using Gmail. I'm guessing you could try to change it to make it work with Facebook only.

I'm not sure how it responds to any errors or exceptions (I'm guessing that would occur if Facebook is not installed), so you might have to test it a bit.

```
    try {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"e-mail address"};
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "E-mail subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "E-mail text");
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); // This is incorrect MIME, but Gmail is one of the only apps that responds to it - this might need to be replaced with text/plain for Facebook
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") ||
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) best = info;
                if (best != null)
                    emailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
                startActivity(emailIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

This is what confuses me though, the first snippet of code you posted works fine for posting to every other app with share intents available, however with Facebook's intent it takes the user to a blank "Write something" facebook page as if it's not sending (or possibly receiving) the text within the EXTRA_TEXT field.

Comment: Hmm, it works just fine with the first one on my tablet. Try it without the EXTRA_SUBJECT field, as stated. That seems to be making the difference.

Comment: Actually, I just checked it and yeah - it's broken. Used to work.

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in my edited first post it appears to be a bug in the Facebook app which has been there since April 2011(!).
Regardless though, thank you for taking the time to repond to my question.

Comment: @MichellBak I am sharing some text, But I want to share long body text for gmail/email and short text for everything else. How can I do that? Any extra field that gmail/email accepts as body? Anyone knows? Please help.

Comment: @MaulikVora I don't think you can do that, as it'd require you to know what the user chooses from the intent dialog.

Comment: @TomSusel Yep, Facebook should get their shit together. It does work when including a URL though. Thanks for the downvote ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I found out you can only share either *Text* **or** *Image*, not both using `Intents`. Below code shares only *Image* if exists, or only *Text* if *Image* does not exits. If you want to share both, you need to use [Facebook SDK from here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

If you use other solution instead of below code, don't forget to specify package name **com.facebook.lite** as well, which is package name of *Facebook Lite*. I haven't test but **com.facebook.orca** is package name of *Facebook Messenger* if you want to target that too.

You can add more methods for sharing with [WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42435212/3736955), [Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42435299/3736955) ...

```
public class IntentShareHelper {

    /**
     * <b>Beware,</b> this shares only image if exists, or only text if image does not exits. Can't share both
     */
    public static void shareOnFacebook(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, String textBody, Uri fileUri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,!TextUtils.isEmpty(textBody) ? textBody : "");

        if (fileUri != null) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setType("image/*");
        }

        boolean facebookAppFound = false;
        List<ResolveInfo> matches = appCompatActivity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana") ||
                info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.lite")) {
                intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                facebookAppFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (facebookAppFound) {
            appCompatActivity.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            showWarningDialog(appCompatActivity, appCompatActivity.getString(R.string.error_activity_not_found));
        }
    }

    public static void shareOnWhatsapp(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, String textBody, Uri fileUri){...}

    private static void showWarningDialog(Context context, String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.close), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create().show();
    }
}
```

For getting **Uri** from File, use below class:

```
public class UtilityFile {
    public static @Nullable Uri getUriFromFile(Context context, @Nullable File file) {
        if (file == null)
            return null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            try {
                return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.my.package.fileprovider", file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
    }

    // Returns the URI path to the Bitmap displayed in specified ImageView       
    public static Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Context context, ImageView imageView) {
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        // Store image to default external storage directory
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            // Use methods on Context to access package-specific directories on external storage.
            // This way, you don't need to request external read/write permission.
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();

            bmpUri = getUriFromFile(context, file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }    
}
```

For writing **FileProvider**, use this link: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did (for text). In the code, I copy whatever text is needed to clipboard. The first time an individual tries to use the share intent button, I pop up a notification that explains if they wish to share to facebook, they need to click 'Facebook' and then long press to paste (this is to make them aware that Facebook has BROKEN the android intent system). Then the relevant information is in the field. I might also include a link to this post so users can complain too...

```
private void setClipboardText(String text) { // TODO
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(text);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label",text);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

Below is a method for dealing w/prior versions

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_share:
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text here");

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); //TODO
         ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "text here");
         clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

        setShareIntent(shareIntent); 

        break;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Lollipop (21), you can use `Intent.EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS` to override the intent for Facebook specifically (and specify a link only)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS

```
private void doShareLink(String text, String link) {
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
  Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_via));

  // for 21+, we can use EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS to support the specific case of Facebook
  // (only supports a link)
  // >=21: facebook=link, other=text+link
  // <=20: all=link
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text + " " + link);
    Bundle facebookBundle = new Bundle();
    facebookBundle.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
    Bundle replacement = new Bundle();
    replacement.putBundle("com.facebook.katana", facebookBundle);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACEMENT_EXTRAS, replacement);
  } else {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
  }

  chooserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems in version 4.0.0 of Facebook so many things has changed. This is my code which is working fine.

```
    /**
     * Facebook does not support sharing content without using their SDK however
     * it is possible to share URL
     *
     * @param content
     * @param url
     */
    private void shareOnFacebook(String content, String url)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: This part does not work properly based on my test
            Intent fbIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            fbIntent.setType("text/plain");
            fbIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
            fbIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url);
            fbIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            fbIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            fbIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.facebook.katana",
                    "com.facebook.composer.shareintent.ImplicitShareIntentHandler"));

            startActivity(fbIntent);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // User doesn't have Facebook app installed. Try sharing through browser.
        }

        // If we failed (not native FB app installed), try share through SEND
        String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + url;
        SupportUtils.doShowUri(this.getActivity(), sharerUrl);
    }
```

Comment: what is SupportUtils?

Answer (score 2):

This solution works aswell. If there is no Facebook installed, it just runs the normal share-dialog. If there is and you are not logged in, it goes to the login screen. If you are logged in, it will open the share dialog and put in the "Share url" from the Intent Extra.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share url");
intent.setType("text/plain");

List<ResolveInfo> matches = getMainFragmentActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("facebook")) {
        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
    }
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did which open Facebook App with Link

```
shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.facebook.katana",
                    "com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ImplicitShareIntentHandler"));

shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  videoUrl);
```

Comment: didn't work for me. probably Facebook has changed the name of ImplicitShareIntentHandler.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void invokeShare(Activity activity, String quote, String credit) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(R.string.share_subject));
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Example text");    
    shareIntent.putExtra("com.facebook.platform.extra.APPLICATION_ID", activity.getString(R.string.app_id));                        
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, activity.getString(R.string.share_title)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow to share plain text data with `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` but You can share text+link with facebook messanger using this, this works fine for me

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text+url link);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I could find to pass a message from my app to facebook was programmatically copy to the clipboard and alert the user that they have the option to paste.  It saves the user from manually doing it; my app is not pasting but the user might.

```
...
if (app.equals("facebook")) {
    // overcome fb 'putExtra' constraint;
    // copy message to clipboard for user to paste into fb.
    ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("post", msg);
    cb.setPrimaryClip(clip);

    // tell the to PASTE POST with option to stop showing this dialogue
    showDialog(this, getString(R.string.facebook_post));
}
startActivity(appIntent);
...
```