# how to use Action_view intent to post on facebook wall?

Tags: android, facebook

how to use `Action_view` intent to post on facebook wall in android?

I have done facebook sdk integration with my Android app it is working fine for me.

But i want to do it with `Action_view` intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI");
```

It works fine for me.

Add your appid and redirected uri to above url.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question:
[Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent/7545574#7545574)

The share Intent for Facebook has been broken for quite some time. They still haven't completely fixed it.

Comment: In this link sharing content on facebook is by ACTION_SEND intent, But I want to do it by ACTION_VIEW intent.