# How to open Facebook and Twitter in android

Tags: android, android-intent

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
  i.setType("text/html");  
  String str = et.getText().toString(); 
  i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,str);  
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share using"));
```

I can't open Facebook and Twitter with this code in Android but other applications like Gmail and Skype are opened successfully. Why's that? And how do I open Facebook and Twitter?

Comment: Do you have Facebook and Twitter installed on that device?

Comment: Not in Emulator,but i install this apk file in my android mobile phone,in that facebook and twitter application is not came but other applications like gmail and skype is came properly.please help me

Comment: I bet you my answer is correct, see below.

Comment: Thank U very much... I done It

Comment: I can not share my text on Facebook with above code. i want to share my message from EditText box.this code does not help me for facebook but for other application works properly

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this code:

```
private void facebooktaPaylas() {
    try {
        String facebookUri = "http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=";
        String marketUri = "your sharing text");
        Intent shareOnFacebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(facebookUri + marketUri));
        startActivity(shareOnFacebookIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void twitterdaPaylas() {
    try {
        String facebookUri = "http://mobile.twitter.com/home?status=";
        String marketUri = "your sharing text";
        Intent shareOnFacebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(facebookUri + marketUri));
        startActivity(shareOnFacebookIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the `MIME` type to `"text/*"`?

It seems that Facebook and Twitter can deal with `"text/plain"` instead of `"text/html"`.

Comment: Is that any chang in menifest file?

Comment: No you just need to change 'i.setType("text/html"); ' to 'i.setType("text/*"); '

Comment: Hey ! I have a little problem arise. i used i.setType("text/*"); all application works successfully. but not in facebook. i used edit textbox, which share my message on facebook. please help me to solve it.

Comment: Probably a bug of Facebook app? see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent