# Facebook share doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I am trying to share a text containing a link via facebook.
My code work perfectly with the facebook messenger application. But not via Facebook app.
In Facebook app i am getting a sharing view with an empty edittext. I Don't want to integrate facebook api and give sharing authorisation. I don't want to do that. I think it can be done only via extras and intent.

My sharing code:

```
private void ShareWebView(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTitle); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented [`og:meta` tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) on the URL you are trying to share?

Comment: i have to implement android sdk for that, i don't want to do that. I just want to share a text via intalled facebook app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. See [Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

And especially this link provided in one of the comment : http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Answer (score 1):

Walkaround: If you do not want to implement it using android SDK

and you want to use

```
private void ShareWebView(){
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.setType("text/plain");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mTitle); // MUST contain 1 url
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
}
```

make sure that `mTitle` contains one LINK.

Why to do that: Although the fact that facebook doesn't work properly it grubs the first url or look like url from the `mTitle` and post-it as share url. It also automatically catch a subtitle and a photo from that url so the post/share is quite acceptable  most of the time avoiding long code implementations!