# How to share Text and Image on Facebook using Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-facebook

How to share Text and Image on Facebook, I am writing a Church Application in which i want to allow user to share text and image along with URL.

I am able to share online app link but not able to share text & image, where i am missing ?

my code looks like this:

```
Button btnFbSharing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbSharing);
        btnFbSharing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                 shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                 shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Church Application");
                 shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana");
                 shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "A new world begin");

                 shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                 PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                 List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
                 for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                        final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                                    activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                    activity.name);
                        shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                        shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                        startActivity(shareIntent);
                       }
                 }                  
            }
        });
```

Comment: U can use Facebook SDK for sharing image,text & link. as facebook doesnt allow to post this from Intent.

Comment: i know facebook sdk will work for me in this case, but i want to know is that possible using Intent ?

Comment: No. Its not possible from Intent.

Comment: @sophie Take look on this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025156/share-intent-via-facebook-for-android-jelly-bean?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025156/share-intent-via-facebook-for-android-jelly-bean?rq=1)

Comment: you can share only url via intent ....

Comment: hope this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951442/how-to-share-image-via-facebook-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I did a lot of research into this as I asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787429/share-image-and-text-to-facebook-on-android)

Basically it is not possible from the facebook app using the package name "com.facebook.katana" as it ignores the extra text when the image is there see this for actual [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/) but can have links when the image is not there. Very annoying I know.

After a lot of looking about I created my own activity using the facebook sdk 3.14.1 which allows images and text here is the [github link](https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent) to the demo project give it a go and let know if it helps you out.

Comment: Hi sorry added the links in just there.

Comment: Not sure if it still works after facebook sdk update to v4.0.1. I'll try it later.

Answer (score 3):

use this for **sharing url** in android via intent chooser... **You dont share any text directly on facebook wallpost**

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String urlToShare = "www.google.com";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Foo bar"); // NB:
                // has no effect!
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);

                // See if official Facebook app is found
                boolean facebookAppFound = false;
                List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager()
                        .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase()
                            .startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
                        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        facebookAppFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
                if (!facebookAppFound) {
                    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="
                            + urlToShare;
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(sharerUrl));
                }

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```