# Share image and text using intent not work in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

i want to share image and text using intent but it is not work 
when facebook intent start it display only image i want to share both text and image

you can check the image here

[image]

```
 List<Intent> targetShareIntents=new ArrayList<Intent>();
                                            Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
                                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                            List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
                                            if(!resInfos.isEmpty())
                                            {

                                                for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos)
                                                {
                                                    String packageName=resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                                                    Log.i("Package Name", packageName);
                                                    if(packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana"))
                                                    {
                                                        String imageurl="/storage/emulated/0/iWally/explosion_3-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg";
                                                        String text="hello how are you";
                                                        Intent intent=new Intent();
                                                        intent.setType("image/*");
                                                        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                                                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
                                                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+imageurl.toString()));
                                                        intent.setPackage(packageName);
                                                        targetShareIntents.add(intent);
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                if(!targetShareIntents.isEmpty())
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("Have Intent");
                                                    Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(targetShareIntents.remove(0), "Choose app to share");
                                                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                                                    startActivity(chooserIntent);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                     Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.facebook.katana"); 
                                                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                                                     startActivity(intent);
                                                    System.out.println("Do not Have facebook");

                                                }
                                            }
```

Comment: i want to share text and image but currently with this code only image shared not text

Answer (score 1):

Hey I did a lot of research into this as I asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787429/share-image-and-text-to-facebook-on-android)

Basically it is not possible from the facebook app using "com.facebook.katana" as it ignores the extra text when and image is there see this for actual [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423/) but can have links when the image is not there. Very annoying I know.

After a lot of looking about I created my own activity using the facebook sdk 3.14.1 which allows images and text [here is the github to the demo project](https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent) give it a go and let know if it helps you out.