# I want to share a Image with caption from my application to Facebook, Is it possible share a image with title in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-contentprovider

```
  SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
 .setBitmap(image)
 .setCaption(des)
 .build();

  SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
 .addPhoto(photo)
 .build(); 
 shareDialog.show(content);
```

This my code, I wanna try to share the image with description and I don't have content URL to share

Comment: For what would you need a content URL?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533773/android-how-to-share-image-with-text-on-facebook-via-intent OR this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787429/share-image-and-text-to-facebook-on-android