# Can't share the text and image both on facebook in android app

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share some text and image on Facebook. The code for that is -:

```
public void clickShareBtn(View view){
        try
        { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
            String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
            sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.krsna \n\n";
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(convertBitmapToFile(bmp));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Radhe", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

But when sharing on Facebook it is only showing image and no description. I think there is some problem with setType(image/*). So can somebody tell what will be the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541823/how-to-share-text-and-image-on-facebook-using-intent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533773/android-how-to-share-image-with-text-on-facebook-via-intent