# Android Share intent - facebook

Tags: android, facebook, share

i want to share something with my friends. so i preferred android share intent.
i used,

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my share text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "share via"));
```

this showing a list of available apps like Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, Message, Skype.. e.t.c..
If i pressed a Twitter in the sense, the above text "my share text" showing in the tweet text box.
But if i select Facebook, the status message not showing.
i want to set the status message programatically.

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android and Facebook share intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Answer (score 2):

Facebook SDK has this bug, it's pretty annoying, I know. But if you set a link (and only a link) as "my share text", it will appear in the facebook share box.

Comment: It's not a bug, Facebook want you to create Facebook apps highly integrated to your Android application.So they want your app to have a really special behavior for Facebook and don't just share some text.

Comment: so why it initially supported that

Comment: thanks it really helped me , link was the all i want

Answer (score 0):

I just built this code and it's working for me:

```
private void shareAppLinkViaFacebook() {
    String urlToShare = "YOUR_URL";

    try {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
        intent1.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ImplicitShareIntentHandler");
        intent1.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
        intent1.setType("text/plain");
        intent1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", urlToShare);
        startActivity(intent1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If we failed (not native FB app installed), try share through SEND
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Facebook does not allow the pre populating of text in the status box like as twitter***. But we can pass the text with url to the Facebook. And it appears below the status box. check below code.

**NOTE : Use Facebook SDK to share [ Recommended ].**

**Native share through intent**

```
 Intent shareIntent= new Intent();
 shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.com");
 shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
 shareIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
 startActivity(shareIntent);
```

**Share through Facebook SDK**

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;

// Sharing in Facebook using the SDK
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

String title = "Demo Title";
String URL = "http://www.google.com";

ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentDescription(URL)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(URL)).build();

shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Check the link below for reference.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Let me know for queries or clarification.

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate instead of using an answer.

Comment: Dear reviewer, sorry for the mistake. check my updated answer.