# Facebook integration without library in android

Tags: android, android-facebook

I have done with facebook integration 
But by adding complete library to my application it was using lot of memory
For this I want to take necessary file only
But I'm unsuccesful for attempting this.
Can i have faacebook integration without adding complete library?
Is there are any tutorials for this? though i have searched i didn't found it.
Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The official Facebook Android sdk is huge and complicated.

I recommend you use this sdk instead:

http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/

It's just 480Kb. I am not affiliated with those guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to share message you can use Share Intent.

But if you want whole lot of functionality like getting profile , contacts , albums, uploading photos , then you need to use sdk.

Secondly the available solution for facebook integration

1. facebook sdk
2. socialauth-android sdk

are lightweight and will not consume much memory.

Edit:

This may help you. You need to check facebook package name com.facebook.katana

[Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Comment: shareintent can i have examples on it

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following tutor [FacebookExample](http://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.in/2012/09/facebook-integration-in-android.html) and you can also download source code with a small FacbookSdk library from this link [Saurabh-12 github](https://github.com/Saurabh-12/SocialIntegrationAndroid.git) Hope this will help you 
Thanks