# Android share intent for Pinterest not working

Tags: android, android-intent, pinterest

I am doing an android share intent for Pinterest but is not fully working. I am able to attach the image but I can't send text to the "description" field in the share window. I've tried different types (text/plain, image/*, image/png) and also tried the ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent type but still no luck. Google chrome share intent works perfectly so I'm sure Pinterest supports this functionality. Here is my code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    if(file != null) intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    intent.setClassName(packageName, name);

    this.startActivity(intent);
```

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a way to share to Pinterest with plain Android intents (without using the [Pinterest SDK](https://developers.pinterest.com/android/)), with help from [Pin It button developer docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/).

Basically you just open an URL like this with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`; the official Pinterest app kindly supports these URLs. (I've earlier used a very similar approach for [sharing to Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/21186753#21186753).)

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
   ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F             
   &media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg
   &description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest
```

And for smoother user experience, [set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String)) the intent to open directly in Pinterest app, if installed.

A complete example:

```
String shareUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388056/";
String mediaUrl = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png";
String description = "Pinterest sharing using Android intents"
String url = String.format(
    "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=%s&media=%s&description=%s", 
     urlEncode(shareUrl), urlEncode(mediaUrl), urlEncode(description));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
filterByPackageName(context, intent, "com.pinterest");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Util methods used above:

```
public static void filterByPackageName(Context context, Intent intent, String prefix) {
    List<ResolveInfo> matches = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) {
            intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            return;
        }
    }
}

public static String urlEncode(String s) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.wtf("", "UTF-8 should always be supported", e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

This is the result on a Nexus 5 with Pinterest app installed:

[image]

And if Pinterest app is *not* installed, sharing works just fine via a browser too:

[image]

Comment: Have you ever figured out a way to share local images using the method above. I am having a tough time figuring out how to send a URL for the image (The website field in the pin) along with an image and description. Here's my related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561031/android-pinterest-share-intent-with-website

Comment: Is it possible to share image from SD card using this method? If I change `mediaUrl` into my file path then pinterest shows notification that, image saving failed.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason pinterest app doesn't comply to the standard (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) so we have to add it separately

```
if(appInfo.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.pinterest"){
        shareIntent.putExtra("com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION","your description");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore for Android 4.4 and older. Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
File imageFileToShare = new File(orgimagefilePath);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);

Intent sharePintrestIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharePintrestIntent.setPackage("com.pinterest");
sharePintrestIntent.putExtra("com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION", text);
sharePintrestIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sharePintrestIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(sharePintrestIntent, PINTEREST);
```