# Android Pinterest share intent with website

Tags: android, pinterest

My Android app has the option to share images via Pinterest by using the native share intent. To pass the description field, I use the com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION field as below:

```
intent.putExtra("com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION", "Text to share");
```

Is there a way to pass the URL for the website that the shared image links to from Pinterest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388056/android-share-intent-for-pinterest-not-working

Comment: If you are referring to the option of using the Pin It button URL, can you explain how that would help share a local image from an Android app. The example show there involves pinning an image from a URL.

Comment: m not sure . please try !  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare));

Comment: Ah...that does not seem to work either. It still picks up the image shared via the URL.