# Share to Pinterest doesn't work on Marshmallow

Tags: android, share, android-6.0-marshmallow, pinterest

I'm trying to share PNG image from local storage with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, imageUri)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
        .putExtra("com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION", "123")
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        .setType("image/png");
return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with");
```

It's working for Facebook, Instagram etc. But for Pinterest, and only on Android 6.0.1 I'm getting this strange exception:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:511)
     at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:578)
     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:122)
     at com.pinterest.common.kit.utils.ImageUtils.getRotationForImage(SourceFile:231)
     at com.pinterest.common.kit.utils.ImageUtils.rotateBitmapIfNeeded(SourceFile:201)
     at com.pinterest.common.kit.utils.ImageUtils.imageFromUri(SourceFile:145)
     at com.pinterest.activity.create.fragment.CreateBaseFragment.setImageUri(SourceFile:604)
     at com.pinterest.activity.create.fragment.CreateBaseFragment.init(SourceFile:330)
     at com.pinterest.activity.create.fragment.CreateBaseFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:120)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:1974)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1067)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1252)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1617)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(SourceFile:339)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:602)
     at com.pinterest.kit.activity.SocialConnectActivity.onStart(SourceFile:111)
     at com.pinterest.kit.activity.BaseActivity.onStart(SourceFile:90)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Can you help to deal with it? Pinterest SDK is not an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388056/android-share-intent-for-pinterest-not-working

Comment: `ACTION_VIEW` is not aplicable as I want all the sharing options appear in the app chooser

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the help of [CommonsWare](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/07/runtime-permissions-files-action-send.html) by using `LegacyCompatFileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by inserting the image into the media store and then using that URI for Pinterest.

```
String urlOfShareImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), outputFile.getPath(), outputFile.getName(), "Share text");
Uri shareImageUri = Uri.parse(urlOfShareImage);
// Pass this URI to the share intent.
```