# Facebook share button for android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to add to my android app sharing to facebook. I found all the code I need for it but is there a share button? I mean is there a premade button (similiar to the android g+ signin button (com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton)? Or if not just the image to put on a button? I looked through the SDK and couldn't find it and their toturial mentions nothing of it.
Thanks.

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/21189010/801437

Comment: What excatly you want to do only share or login with fb..??

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I've read it but saw nothing to mention a button.  user1632209 only share not login. I want a button class that has the facebook logo that says share or at least the image so I can place on a button. Just seems to me that is something that will be out there.