# Android Share text not showing up in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have a share button, which when clicked I want to open a share windows, so the user can share this text in social networks. The problem is facebook, it is not accepting the EXTRA_TEXT passed onto the intent

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

every other share option (twitter, tumblr...) works fine, just facebook is giving problems...
How can I solve this without having to create a whole new class with facebook sdk just for this purpose??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Facebook application does not handle either the EXTRA_SUBJECT or
>   EXTRA_TEXT fields.

Here is bug link : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Comment: can I at least make a "shared via MyApp" at the end of the post?

Comment: They should remove ACTION_SEND intent filter from their manifest if they don't want predefined texts to be posted. What if my app wants to post a photo with a description(which user already added in my app, So asking the user to retype the same is very bad).

Answer (score 1):

You cant Share Text in Facebook as Facebook discards it and asks you in its application to write the text like what in your mind.

see this report

[Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Comment: can I at least make a "shared via MyApp" at the end of the post?