# Android app share on Facebook, Instagram and Twitter

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter

In my application I want to be able to share some content which are images from my app to Facebook, Instagram and Twitter. I know i can send a broadcast to do that using the below code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("plain/text");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the text that will be shared.");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

but my problem is that I wanna get a callback that tells me if the user has shared the content(image) or not. Is there any kind of way to do this? What about the Facebook sdk? Does it provide such a functionality? I've searched about Instagram and it seems that they don't provide such a funcionality. What about Twitter?

Comment: without facebook sdk, i dont think so you can share things from android to facebook.

Comment: @Softcoder you can easily share anything on facebook without its sdk. it's a simple broadcast and facebook app itself handles it with its own dialog and stuff. but there will be no callback for that. I assume facebook sdk will give you some callback to handle whether the content is shared or not . but thanks anyway

Comment: plz see this       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402706/android-share-text-not-showing-up-in-facebook/25402734#25402734

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily to get call back.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("plain/text");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the text that will be shared.");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

Use **startActivityForResult** instead of **startActivity** and override **OnActivityResult** in which check your result code is **RESULT_OK** or not.If it is that you have successfully posted your content other wise your post was not successful.

Comment: But I think if the application doesn't send any result, the default result will be **RESULT_OK**... isn't that true? I'm just asking

Comment: Give it a try working or not I think this should work.

Comment: it doesn't work. It always returns 0 because the activity should handle the resultcode which in my case facebook doesn't. I should go and check sdk