# how to add simple share via facebook and all other supported applications

Tags: android, share

Hello I am giving an share option in my app,I am going to share simple text and a link to play store for my app,I added following code but when i select share via facebook then text is no already there when it opens post window,while for twitter and gmail sharing i can see my text in compose email text area.

i have written following code in my fragment...

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey there i am using this App. To download on Play store click here "+link);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is no longer supported share via intent. You must create a code to find whether you have a facebook app on your device. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Facebook. you can's share text in facebook. Read this documentation..

This is a bug from Facebook, not your code
Facebook will NOT fix this bug, they say it is "by design" that they broke the Android share system : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423
use the SDK or share only URL.
Tips: you could cheat a little using the web page title as text for the post.
shar