# Android post status intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to post a text on facebook without the facebook sdk.

I already see how can I share link with facebook

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Foo bar"); // NB: has no effect!
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);

// See if official Facebook app is found
        boolean facebookAppFound = false;
        List<ResolveInfo> matches = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
                intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                facebookAppFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

// As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
        if (!facebookAppFound) {
            String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I want to do the same but with simple text..
What can I do ?

Comment: By simple text you mean?

Comment: @Pavlos i mean plain text, not URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't really do this! I have a look at the following link, as it says it's a know bug and Facebook doesn't seem to care fixing it. [Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Comment: But with the facebook SDK I can share a simple text ? (that would mean posting a text )

Comment: With the Facebook SDK you can do everything!