# i want to add "share the image to Facebook" feature in my android application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I Created a app which shows images to the user. User can download and set the images as wallpaper apart from that i want that user can share the image to facebook? I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `Intent` to share your Image in Facebook.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = null;
if(imageUri!=null){
    screenshotUri = Uri.parse(imageUri);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
}
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using..."));
```

Make sure your Image `Uri` is not null. This will launch an Intent that will display all the applications that you can share the image with. Among those, Facebook.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is still works? Because facebook is no longer supporting intent.putExtra. You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent).

Comment: I just tested my code and I managed to successfully publish it. Facebook ignores EXTRA_SUBJECT or EXTRA_TEXT fields, not Intent.EXTRA_STREAM field.

Comment: Thanks for your help....in my app i have full-screen option where user click on image to view it in full screen. in full screen image i have options like set as wallpaper and download image i want " Share to Facebook icon between them. for that i have various pages i don't know where to put that code. If u want i can share that pages with you?

Comment: What do you mean, pages?

Comment: by " Pages " i mean for full screen i have **FullScreenViewActivity.java** and main class is **MainActivity.java** and other layout classes....here is the link of the app i am making....u will understand by seeing this link....and sorry if i am asking or too much help [link] (http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-2/).  Thank You