# how to upload images and links to facebook from android

Tags: android, facebook, hyperlink

i have used this code to upload image to facebook successfully

```
Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(), bmp, new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(FacebookUpload.this,
                                "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

now the problem is i want to add a link as i upload images, how i do this, the link has to appear under the images, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can upload it with FaceBook API or with Intent.

Try to share to facebook with Intent. Maybe it's an easier way after improving it in your code. See
[Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, i have managed to upload the link n image as i want now i have a weird problem that i can upload images only from my Facebook account, whenever i try to upload from a different account i can log in but on clicking the upload button i get redirected to that screen in which Facebook asks if this app can access this that etc etc, what is going wrong here