# facebook not showing message by sending via Intent

Tags: java, android, facebook

```
public void shareMessage(){    
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     
    intent.setType("text/plain");   
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);    
    getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

}

When I use "text/plain", Facebook comes up as an option but the text does not load up when selecting it. But the text does load for Twitter,email, SMS.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: "Has anyone else encountered this problem" is not the kind of question to ask on this site. State a specific problem you're having that may or may not have a specific solution and someone will likely help you. As stated, it is unclear what kind of help you expect.

Comment: you cannot do that. you must using facebook sdk

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments , Facebook has disabled the share intent a few years back [Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent) , it doesn't handle EXTRA_SUBJECT or EXTRA_TEXT fields,

Use the Facebook api , Instructions found here --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#share_options