# I want to use share intent in my android application

Tags: android, facebook

How to create some specific `share intent` for social media?

Currently, my code is like this:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {});
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The EssexPass");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Deal Name: " + Bussinessname);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Deal: " + deals);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Address: " + city + "," + country);
Log.e("Share intetn", "25th April ::-" + share);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Deal"));
```

I use this code for `share intent` but in `facebook` I can't share.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433 or http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/get-social-using-android-intents-to-share-a-link/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bug in Facebook app. Here you can find more details: [Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

> Facebook will NOT fix this bug, they say it is "by design" that they
>   broke the Android share system :
>   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Comment: it's work but i not use any type of SDK.