# how can Share URL with content on facebook from application?

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am trying to share play store URL from my application with some my title and description but I an not getting content and title of application on shared data. Please can anybody help me out.

here is my code,

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("My Application")
            .setContentDescription("Check out My Allpication.")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana"))
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(ActivityOptions.this, "There is no Facebook application available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not "allow" text on sharing, only a link.

See more information on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent).

Comment: But I am using facebook sdk Not Intent.

Comment: Try adding your link to the .setContentDescription()

Comment: That is not allowing to share any content.

Comment: I'd say if none of them (title, description and URL) work, just stick to native Android code using an Intent. See this answer for example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent/21189010#21189010