# Android Post to Facebook without using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I was wondering if it is possible for us to post to Facebook without using the Facebook SDK, but rather launch the native Facebook app with specific content to be posted?

In iOS, we can use the Social Framework, how do we approach this problem in Android?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to invoke the share dialog without using the Facebook SDK using an `Intent`. Unfortunately it is not possible to share custom text. If this is a requirement you have to integrate their SDK.

For more details on the intent solution, have a look at following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189010/5199788