# Share Score on Facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I want to share my game score on facebook. I checked lots of links and every post people are saying that **POSTING** on facebook using **INTENT** is **not possible**.If we are using intent than we can **share only link**.

If we have to **share something on facebook** than we have to use [FaceBook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android).

I have another doubt that all questions and answers were posted **before Year 2014**. Is any **new thing come** after year 2014.

My actual question is that, Is it possible to **share score** on Facebook using **Intent** or i have to use **Facebook SDK** ?

below is the intent code which i used for my application which is not working ......

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share on"));
```

and below is the FacebookSDK code ...and **Problem** in this it is **not showing score** on the Post **only link image** is showing, and **title & description** is missing.

```
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

            shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
             if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                        linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentTitle(title)
                                .setContentDescription(description)
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(link)).
                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageLink)   
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                    }
```

I used ShareDialog because

**The Share dialog switches to the native Facebook for Android app, then returns control to your app after a post is published. If the Facebook app is not installed it will automatically fallback to the web-based dialog.**

Below is the output ..........

[image: output]

@pravin this is error coming after your share API use

[image: o]

@Pravin this is my code of your share answer........

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

        Button mShare= (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);

        mShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                        .putString("og:type", "game.achievement")
                        .putString("og:title", "Name of your game")
                        .putString("og:description", "description. You can share your score here")
                        .putString("game:points", "445")
                        .build();

                ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                        .setActionType("games.achieves")
                        .putObject("game", object)
                        .build();




                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                            .setPreviewPropertyName("game")
                            .setAction(action)
                            .build();

                    ShareDialog.show(Facebook.this, content);
                }
            }
        });
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    }
```

Thanx in advance ................

Comment: As per my understanding, facebook is not allowing only text sharing, so you need to share small image with text and by that way only you can share score

Comment: so you want score to populated in facebook share but score is not displaying correct ? you are using facebook SDK ?

Comment: yes i am using FaceBookSDK .Is it working on your side ?? I used book example it working but game is not working using this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android#sharedialog

Comment: @sushildlh Are you getting any other exceptions in above posted code ? Or it is allow you to opens share dialog ?

Comment: No0o0o0  Exception .....

Comment: @sushildlh I have asked that because generally the *FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());* should be written before *super.onCreate* not after that.

Answer (score 8):

After long searching i found this as work for me in my Project till the actual answer will come ..........

```
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

            shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
            if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setQuote("Hi Guys I have completed Game 30 in 19 seconds  in this game")
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jUej7mN6M6iulmuwmW6Mk28PrzXgl-Ebn-MpTmkmwtOfj5f0hvnuw8j0NEzK0GuKoDE=w300-rw"))
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobtraffiq.numbertap&hl=en"))
                        .build();

                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                }
```

**NOTE:-In this code its shared a quota. If any one get other answer please post with output.**

Output:-

[image: output]

**Please post guys if you get the actual answer of this question ....**

Thank you for all the user who make their effort .......

I have learn many thing due to your answers .......

enjoy coding .........

Comment: post your question and let me know your issue with full error logs

Comment: could you please take a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080921/sharedialog-dismiss-immediately

Answer (score 3):

**Scores API**

If you just want to share score you can use [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements#scores)(Read `Create or Update a Player's Score` section). There is very less and unclear information in provided link so below code snippet might work for you.

```
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putInt("score", 100);

    new GraphRequest(
    your_access_token,
    "/USER_ID/scores",
    param,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

**Achievements API**

Use [Achievements API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements#achievements) if you want to publish achievements in your game and reward players with scores for completing those achievements.You have to use `Open Graph Stories` to publish your game achievements on Facebook. Before publishing stories on behalf of people, You will have to submit them for review. Read [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android) for more information.There are two ways to publish an Open Graph story:

1. Using the Share dialog
2. Using your own custom interface

As you are using share dialog, I am going to throw some light on how to post game score using share dialog.

1. Create an object with the object type `game.achievement` and set the properties on that object.

> ```
> ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
>         .putString("og:type", "game.achievement")
>         .putString("title", "Title of the achievement type.")
>         .putString("og:description", "description. You can share your score here")
>         .putInt("game:points", Points in integer)
>   .putString("og:url", "url of achievement type") 
>   .putString("og:image", "image url") 
>   .putString("fb:app_id", "The App ID that owns this achievement type") 
>   .build();
> ```

In above code snippet key is [Object Properties](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties) and game.achievement is [Object Type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#object-type). Here is documentation for [game:points](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/game.achievement).

2. Then create an action and link the object to the action.

> ```
> ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
>     .setActionType("games.achieves")
>     .putObject("game", object)
>     .build();
> ```

You can find different `ActionTypes` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#action-type).

3. Finally, create the content model to represent the Open Graph story.

> ```
> ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
>     .setPreviewPropertyName("game")
>     .setAction(action)
>     .build();
> ```
>
> *All objects and action types in your code must be lowercase. All
>   property names require namespaces.*

4. Present the Share dialog by using the `show` method on `ShareDialog`.

> ShareDialog.show(activityOrFragment, content);

**Summary:-**

> The Scores API and Achievements API make it easy to build social
>   leaderboards, persist player scores and award achievements to players
>   in a social and cross-platform format. With the Scores API, you can
>   store and reset a player's high-score and pull back a list of their
>   friends' scores to populate a leaderboard. With the Achievements API,
>   you can define a list of custom achievements that players can complete
>   in your game, along with a score value that can be earned with each
>   achievement.

**Note:-**

> Both the **Scores API** and **Achievements API** are only available for apps
>   that are categorized as **Games**.
>
> Because these API let developers write information about player game
>   state to the Graph API, they both require `publish_actions` permissions,
>   which is subject to Login Review. To retrieve Score and Achievement
>   information about a player's friends, both the player and their
>   friends need to grant the `user_friends` permission.

Hope this will provide you and other users enough information on game integration with `Facebook`.

Comment: I used your share API it gives me error which i was posted on question.Please have look.

Comment: Paste your code snippet. It seems like you might have to use score API in conjunction of achievement API. Also there is very less documentation regarding it.

Comment: i have added code of your implementation .....please have look ..... Please if possible please some of your code regarding this concept ......

Comment: game:points must be integer. If you just want to post score than use score API and instead of USER_ID use user ID of respective user. In my answer I separate both (scores API and achievements API ) in different sections, so take reference from it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: please check the code it says `.putString("game:points", Points in integer)
` method is `putstring` how it would accept the integer ........

Comment: Use putInt for game:points instead of putString. I have updated my answer. Pls check.

Comment: Updated my answer check with that.

Comment: please identify that what are the changes . It is very difficult to identify last code and new code

Comment: Making changes in ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder() in achievement API section(no.1 section).

Comment: same error is coming which i posted image in question

Comment: Is it working on your side ?? I used book example it working but game is not working using this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android#sharedialog and error is coming same as the above i mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120795/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-pravin-divraniya).

Comment: instead of game i put achievement `.putObject("achievement", object)` and `.setPreviewPropertyName("achievement")` it gives me new **error :- Achievement has not been registered for your application.** will you please tell me how i register my application.

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below snippet,

call wherever you want like below

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mContext);
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(mContext);

shareScoreonFB("345"); // just pass your score here in string format. call this inside click listener.

// GLOBAL FUNCTION TO SHARE SCORE ON FB 
void shareScoreonFB(String score)
{
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Your score is : "+score)
                    .setContentDescription("Any description that you needed")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobtraffiq.numbertap&hl=en")).build();
            shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

**NOTE: Make sure you initialize the Facebook SDK.**

Hope this helps you, let me know for queries.

Comment: use this link in your code https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobtraffiq.numbertap&hl=en and please tell me is title or decription is coming or not

Comment: place your link inside contenturl. check my updated answer.

Comment: bro i already did that once you try it you got why i was m posted this question .......The image i posted on question that show after putting your code ..........Only image is coming , title and description is missing .....

Comment: bro.. just use the above snippet only and just comment all your existing code. just paste this function in your activity and call it inside share button.

Comment: NumberTap Image is coming which i was posted in question after posting your code .......

Comment: have look on question i posted image which is coming after use of your code ............

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Facebook SDK uses a background Activity for the actual data transfer, but you still need to make your own activity, its layout, and the examples on [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) show you how to create your own Sharing and Login tools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13221364)

Comment: @AADTechnical Noted for the future

Comment: you can in fact improve your above post by including the essential parts! Of course do the same for your future Posts too...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Facebook SDK to do this, I think the main reason is about security.

This is a simple snippet for photo sharing example (not related to your question but i think you know you can't not do it by using Intent):

```
private void shareImage() {
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bmp)
                .setCaption("Simple puzzle")
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, null);
    }
```

Comment: @sushildlh here is all you need :) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Yes, that's the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are **3** things you should do :
*1)* Categorize your app as Games on Facebook Developers 
*2)* Use the Achievements API and Scores API 
*3)* Facebook for Developers officially has an answer to your question. Please refer to the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements

> [ OPTIONAL ]

If you want to study about General Sharing from your app by users than this link  [Facebook SharingAddit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) might also help you in as General Sharing of content from your app