# Facebook Image preview missing only when sharing from Android

Tags: android, facebook, share

I added a sharing feature on my app like this:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");

// Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide what to do with it.
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, toShare);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getResources().getString(R.string.share)));
```

When I choose to share with Facebook I can see the correct Image preview:
[image]

but then on facebook the image preview is missing:
[image]

And this is happening only when I share from Android, if I share from iOS the image preview is displayed correctly. Do you have any idea what can be the issue?
Here an example of the shared link: http://pixide.org/it/share/?t=F61CAD079F61F540757E569F68332275

Thanks

Comment: Where did you store the image ?

Comment: the image is actually on the facebook CDN

Comment: Can u post the whole code including "toShare" bundle ?

Comment: I already posted the whole code. toShare is simply a string and you can assume it's "http://pixide.org/it/share/?t=F61CAD079F61F540757E569F68332275"

Comment: Add the image explicitly? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Yeah I know, but my aim was to use the "native" sharing method

Comment: have you checked here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533773/android-how-to-share-image-with-text-on-facebook-via-intent

Comment: @StefanoGiacone go throgh this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/38929075/5305430

Comment: I do not want to force the user to share on facebook, I want to let the user chosse his preferred sharing method, so I need to go native

Comment: Have you tried with `Share Dialog` of `Facebook SDK` ?