# Sharing text post on Facebook Wall from my application using Facebook Sdk Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Please tell me how can I share text post on facebook wall from my application using facebook sdk, as I have tried a lot of things but still I am not able to share a text post on the facebook wall.

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759057/share-score-on-facebook-android

Comment: @sushildlh this is not exactly what I am looking for, In the particular link that you have provided they are sharing that Quote along with the url and I want is only the text post without any url