# How to share image and text on pinterest using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, pinterest

I want to share image and text on pinterest using intent. Any ideas?

Comment: I am new developer for this task. I have tried with setting intent type as image & set static web image url for testing to share image link on pinterest.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759057/share-score-on-facebook-android

Comment: I have check this link but i think this is for facebook sharing option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first check pintrest application is installed into device or not using this function.

```
    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
       PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
       boolean app_installed;
       try {
           pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
           app_installed = true;
       }
       catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
           app_installed = false;
       }
       return app_installed;
   }
```

If this function returns you true than you can call this below line.

```
File imageFileToShare = new File(orgimagefilePath);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);

Intent sharePintrestIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharePintrestIntent.setPackage("com.pinterest");
sharePintrestIntent.putExtra("com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION", text);
sharePintrestIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sharePintrestIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(sharePintrestIntent, PINTEREST);
```

This was work for me. please check it.

Comment: What if I dont have Pinterest app installed in my device ? will this code work in that particular scenario ?

Comment: no it will returns you `activityNotFound` so you have to first check the application is installed or not.

Comment: Okay got it. Do you have any idea how to share on pinterest without pinterest app?

Comment: Go throw this link :
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/android/