# ShareDialog dismiss immediately

Tags: android, facebook, fbsdksharedialog

I 'm trying to add a ShareFacebook button in my android app.

The code works when I use my FB account, the one I used with Facebook Developer Console and I can share the link on my FB with no problem.

But, when I tested the app with an other FB account,  the share dialog **appears and disappeares** **very fast**.

I have no clue why, any help?

Here's my code:

```
facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ScoreActivity.this);

                if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("..."))
                            .build();

                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);


                }

        }

    });
```

Since I can share with my Fb then I guess the code is fine, So it's probably a configuration or a parameter issues, but I have no idea where to start. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you found any stack trace?
You must look if you have initialized facebook SDK or not

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    // this part is optional
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { ... });
```

and if it is showing, and dismissing, then there must be

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: I have initilized the FBSdk and added the provider in manifest.xml

Comment: Ohh, i got it...make sure your application will be only work with test IDs you added in facebok, if you will use other IDs, the requests will be denied by facebook, whenever you deploy the app, please make sure to modify the configuration for release, i have faced this issue too..

Comment: can you please explain how tomodify configuration for release .

Comment: 11. Disable Development Mode
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#development-mode
New Facebook apps exist in development mode by default. This limits published actions and related objects such as friend tagging to Facebook Timelines owned by a developer of the application.

Once your application is ready for public use you can switch from development mode to public mode to allow your app to interact with Facebook accounts not associated with your app.

Comment: Read this page and please mark my answer as final if you found it useful. :)