# Sharing button don't run with the facebook (Text Empty)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, share

Sharing Button runs with Viber and What's app
but don't run with Facebook,
just blank area.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
bt = findViewById(R.id.imageShareButton);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = versesText.getText().toString();
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Perfect Verses");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody + "\n" + "Read More...");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
             }
         });
```

My app's link on GooglePlay,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samuel.perfectverses

Comment: Have you already tried with the solutions posted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent) question?

Comment: This issue is going to be closed by design because our API does not support pre-filling the message for users as seen in our Policy Documentation here

Comment: I think it's not possible .. this is sad  :(

Comment: You will need to use Facebook's SDK to allow sharing on their app. You can read the official docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android and Facebook share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545254/android-and-facebook-share-intent)

Comment: I tried the next answer of the link you sent to me. it works for url only but when I replaced the url with text didn't work..

Comment: His code don't open chooser.. just directly open Facebook with his link

Comment: That is exactly what Facebook is saying: URLs work but trying to pre-fill text is against their policy. Use Spotify as an example: sharing on whatsapp will create pre-filled text but sharing on Facebook won't. That is the best you can get

Comment: so bad validation. thanks Nicolas so much for your help it's so kind of you man.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MET9P.png) I run your code and I got this, I think you forgot to add Action.

```
val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sharingIntent.type = "text/plain"
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, titl + "\n" + "Read More..." + "\n" + link)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)))
```

Comment: in fact i added the SEND ACTION before, but it don't work for Facebook. I update the code in question by some of codes you sent but it don't works with Facebook too. it works only with Gmail and Viber.

Comment: @samuel I tried your code, it is working fine and I updated with the image. are you testing in which device?

Comment: Samsung Note 5 & HTC Desire 728 Ultra.

Comment: is it working with Facebook?? or is it put an text inside" what's in your mind"

Comment: I posted to you my app if you'd like to test it

Comment: Have you installed the Facebook app?

Comment: yes sure and it opens normally but don't put my text into "what's in your mind", it does with the sms and with the gmail and viber

Comment: @Samuel can you check it in lower device version, I think default Android intent does not work in the higher version specially Samsung high version device. Actually, i have also stuck in  Default intent which is working fine but in higer version of samsung was not working.

Comment: @Samuel sometime some app does not support Extra_Text use Extra_Stream, See my updated code, I forgot to remind you.

Comment: I tried Samsung S2 but it didn't work too, I'll try stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
String packageName = "com.facebook.katana";
String fullUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=..";
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (intent == null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(fullUrl));
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setClassName(packageName ,
                    "com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your title text");
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Comment: I tried this link but it works only for url, not works for text. I think this is Facebook validation.