# React Native: write in AsyncStorage with java

Tags: java, storage, react-native

So I have this text on the java-side that arrives from an `Intent`, which I'd like to save to `AsyncStorage` to being able to access it through React afterwards.

Any chance I can achieve this?

I have:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.content.Intent;


import com.facebook.react.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();

        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "BrowseItLater", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);

        // This code is from http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            handleSendText(intent);
        }        
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            // How can I handle this ????
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

Or is there any other solution to make `MainActivity.java` communicate with JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite some fight **I finally found a solution**. It doesn't use `AsyncStorage` as I read in the source code AsyncStorage could actually be located differently (SQLite, or something else) depending on the phone. Would be dirty to duplicate this logic.

Instead, I created a module like [the doc suggests](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content) and passed the `inputText` as an argument to the `.addPackage(new EphemeralStoragePackage(inputText))` call in `MainActivity.java`.

The module exposes a method `readOnceAsync` to the JS world, which I can later call with:

```
NativeModules.EphemeralStorage.readOnceAsync((text :string) => {
  if (text.length) {
    this._addValue(text); // this method is in charge of storing in AsyncStorage
  }
})
```

---

Here's the detail:

```
// android/app/src/main/java/com/appname/modules/ephemeralstorage/EphemeralStorageModule.java

package com.browseitlater.modules.ephemeralstorage;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

import java.util.Map;

public class EphemeralStorageModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private String inputText;

  public EphemeralStorageModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext, String _inputText) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.inputText = _inputText;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "EphemeralStorage";
  }

  public String getInputText() {
    return inputText;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void readOnceAsync(Callback successCallback) {
    successCallback.invoke(getInputText());
    this.inputText = null;
  }

}
```

And

```
// android/app/src/main/java/com/appname/modules/ephemeralstorage/EphemeralStoragePackage.java
package com.browseitlater.modules.ephemeralstorage;

import android.app.Activity;

import java.util.*;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;


public class EphemeralStoragePackage implements ReactPackage {
  private String inputText;

  public EphemeralStoragePackage(String _inputText) {
    super();
    this.inputText = _inputText;
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.add(new EphemeralStorageModule(reactContext, getInputText()));
    return modules;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  public String getInputText() {
    return inputText;
  }

}
```

Finally in `MainActivity.java`, my `onCreate` method looks like:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    String inputText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
      .setApplication(getApplication())
      .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
      .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
      .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
      .addPackage(new EphemeralStoragePackage(inputText))
      .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
      .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
      .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "BrowseItLater", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write a native module, you can do this in `MainActivity.java`

Declare a global variable inside MainActivity class (don't forget to import `com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier`):

```
private ReactDatabaseSupplier mReactDatabaseSupplier;
```

Inside `onCreate`method initialize the global variable:

```
mReactDatabaseSupplier = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Declare a private method to save the key/value pair inside `AsyncStorage`

```
private void saveKeyValuePair(String key, String value) {
    String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO catalystLocalStorage VALUES (?, ?);";
    SQLiteStatement statement = mReactDatabaseSupplier.get().compileStatement(sql);
    try {
        mReactDatabaseSupplier.get().beginTransaction();
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindString(1, key);
        statement.bindString(2, value);
        statement.execute();
        mReactDatabaseSupplier.get().setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("YOUR_TAG", e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            mReactDatabaseSupplier.get().endTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("YOUR_TAG", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can save key/value pairs like this (inside `onCreate`, for example):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactDatabaseSupplier = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    saveKeyValuePair("myAsyncStorageKey", "myValueInAsyncStorageKey");
```

}

This is a simple way to save in `AsyncStorage` of a React Native application. Consider writing a native module.