# Add link to Twitter account within activity on Android

Tags: android, twitter

Is there a way that I can add a link to my twitter account that will open the users twitter app if installed and go to my twitter page?

I don't want to send tweets via twitter...

Comment: see this question. It should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application

Comment: @Vladimir I don't think that question helps him actually?  See my answer.

Comment: @Vladimir dbyrne has it correct in his answer below. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the user to click a link from your Activity, and be forwarded to your twitter account's profile page inside whatever twitter app they have installed.

I don't think there is any way to do this.  You can [interface with twitter apps using an intent](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-interfacing-with-twitter-applications/) if you want to send out a tweet, but I am unaware of any twitter apps that can handle intents to display a particular user's profile page.  Your best bet is to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display your mobile twitter page to the user.

Related: [Hello WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Comment: You have understood me correctly. From my various Googles, I figured this would be the answer, but thought I'd ask it anyway! Thanks