# Android ACTION_SEND different texts for each application

Tags: android

I'm using an Intent with ACTION_SEND and I need to share different texts. I need to send a text for Gmail and I need to send other text for twitter. depends on the application. Can I get the application selected by the user before the application sends the text shared?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Intent for Twitter application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application)

Comment: check your answer here
[Twidroid’s ACTION_SEND intent][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/4715465#4715465

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/82788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can't be sure which application will receive your ACTION_SEND intent.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/2077361#2077361) explains why you probably shouldn't do customization based on predicting which application the user will end up in.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/4715465#4715465) explains a workaround for TwiDroyd, which you probably shouldn't use but may help you in the short term.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get the application selected by the user before the application sends the text shared. For this you have to make a workaround, i.e.:

You have to get list of which applications are supported for this intent by:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
List activities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent,0);
```

By getting the list. we can built a alert dialog and then make listener for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea of getting the user selected application to send something.

But you can choose programatically the apk to open your intent using an IntentResolver.