# Set a different text to an ACTION_SEND intent according to the application selected in the chooser

Tags: android, share

How can I set a different content (different text, image/no image...) to an **ACTION_SEND** intent?
Basically I'd like to have a long text and an image for an email, just the long text for Facebook, and a short text for Twitter... I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313802/android-action-send-different-texts-for-each-application), but there is no answer to the question.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer still stands is that u cannot do that, there is no way to identify which application is going to handle ur intent, that choice is left onto the user. You can provide user options for facebook and twitter directly which might be useful