# How to know which application is selected to do Intent.ACTION_SEND? (by using newer Android APIs, e.g., 4.0+)

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this is a frequently asked question in early days, for example, we can easily found the following related discussions:

- [How to know which intent is selected in Intent.ACTION_SEND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495909/how-to-know-which-intent-is-selected-in-intent-action-send)
- [Set a different text to an ACTION_SEND intent according to the
  application selected in the chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409931/set-a-different-text-to-an-action-send-intent-according-to-the-application-selec)

However, Android API evolved in these years (2011~end of 2014), I would like to know if there is any new way to know which application is selected to do `Intent.ACTION_SEND`? Or this is still not possible?

Comment: I can vaguely guess that you can use startactivityforresult(intent) and then on recieving the result you can print the package name. This is a wild guess. And it's a good question

Comment: You could create your own chooser , rather than system chooser, so that you can know which item was clicked