# auto-tweet through user account from Android App

Tags: android

I want to give Auto-tweet option in my App to the user. When the user chooses the auto-tweet option then onwards **users data is tweeted through his Twitter account** ( but not through the App twitter account) on certain Event (predefined by the App).

Is this feasible? If so can someone please tell how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Android Intent for Twitter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application) you can use an intent to specify that you want to tweet, and then any application that handles tweeting can accept this intent. Is that what you want to do?