# Problems sharing combined text and image with SHARE INTENT on Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

I want to give the user the possibility to share a Image and a Text with Twitter and Facebook.

Actually my code can launch Android's share intent and if the user selects Facebook, all works fine, the Image is attached and the text is shown on the body of the new status.

But something is wrong with Twitter, if i only put a Image all works fine, the image is detected by twitter and automatically uploaded to twipic, then twitter posts the link of the image on the tweet. But if i put a image and a text, then, twitter doesn't detect the image and it only puts the text on the tweet, the image is ignored. What is wrong?

this is my code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.jpg");
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new status");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: Have a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/9151983#9151983

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specify MIME type also for the text. `"text/plain"` is the type of text data MIME. Try using `"*/*"` as MIME, so you can send any generic data type.

Also try changing `ACTION_SEND` to `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` which specialized for delivering multiple data.

More info about ACTION_SEND_MULTPLE and handling MIME types:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I tryed with */* and didn't works. I can't use ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE because it doesn't exists, at least on Android 1.5.

Comment: Now i tryed with ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and Android api 4, and it doesn't works.

Comment: Well, research if twitter application can do multiple data requests to its API...Does it work with facebook app?

Comment: Got this to work, using ACTION_SEND and image/* as the type (Android 4.0, need to test on lower API versions but hopefully should still work.)

Comment: @brk3 i am getting "image could not be loaded" error while doing this.Can you suggest me?

Answer (score 24):

You can still try with `ACTION_SEND`, without using the `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` resulted in a force close, when I tried to create new intents for sharing to Gmail, G+, etc.

This worked perfect for me:

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image.jpg");
    shareIntent.setType("*/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new status");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    return shareIntent;
```

Comment: how do you construct the uri?

Comment: @ Paschalis : i try your cod ebut when i shre with facebook it give me toast like **"please attach only photos or a single videos"**  any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: Hi @HarshalKalavadiya. I can barely remember why I needed this.
Are you sure you have set the generic type `"*/*"`?

Comment: @ Paschalis Yes is set generic type `"*/*"`