# How to share both text and image in the share intent (email and gmail)

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-image

I would like to make a share button for both **gmail** and the **rom email app** . The problem is how to share both image and text?

For the image , I can provide either file uri / bitmap / whatever need and I only need to share **one** image.

```
   final Intent result = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    result.setType("plain/text");
    result.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { recipient });
    result.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    result.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: check this tutorial this might help
https://hasithdevs.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/android-share-textimages-using-share-intent/

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296605/problems-sharing-combined-text-and-image-with-share-intent-on-twitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find ans from below code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {""}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EMAIL_BODY);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+fileName));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sharing Options"));
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: this solution doesn't work for Facebook/Whatsupp, it only share the image, not the text.