# Sharing image failed

Tags: android, image, android-intent, sharing

I'm trying to share an `image` but I don't know why I'm failing, could you help me please?

```
String imageUrl = web.get(position).getImage();
    if (!imageUrl.startsWith("http://") && !imageUrl.startsWith("https://"))
        imageUrl = "http://" + imageUrl;

    Button button = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.condividi);
    final String finalImageUrl = imageUrl;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, web.get(position).getTitle());
            File file = writebitmaptofilefirst("the image", finalImageUrl );
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path );
            Intent send = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
            context.startActivity(send);
        }
    });
```

---

```
public static File writebitmaptofilefirst(String filename, String source) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/temp_images");
    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    OutputStream outStream = null;


    File file = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), filename + ".jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".jpg");
        Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL(source);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return file;

}
```

**EDIT**

```
String imageUrl = web.get(position).getImage();
    if (!imageUrl.startsWith("http://") && !imageUrl.startsWith("https://"))
        imageUrl = "http://" + imageUrl;

    Button button = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.condividi);
    final String finalImageUrl = imageUrl;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, web.get(position).getTitle());
            String file = writebitmaptofilefirst("ndp_image", finalImageUrl);
            //Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file );
            Intent send = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
            context.startActivity(send);
        }
    });

    return rowView;

}

public static String writebitmaptofilefirst(String filename, String source) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/temp_images/");
    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    OutputStream outStream = null;


    File file = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), filename + ".jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".jpg");
        Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL(source);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return file.getAbsolutePath();

}
```

Comment: What problem do you get? A crash? If so, please post the LogCat too

Comment: @user2340612 I'm getting no crashes, when I'm about to send the files using a social app It just appears a message like : **Sharing failed, please try again** (in the case of Whatsapp) or **Impossible to upload the image** (in the case of Instagram)

Comment: Are you sure that you need both the `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` extras? I guess that you need only the second one

Comment: But I need to share some text with an image

Comment: maybe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296605/problems-sharing-combined-text-and-image-with-share-intent-on-twitter) can help you

Comment: I've already tried with those options but nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permissions to your manifest

Remove space from file name (the image). With space you need decode the uri.  You should  paass the full path **return file.getAbsolutePath()**. You are just passing the file name.
In the case of file exists your not storing in the same path.  You were not included the dictionary.   extranlstoragepath+/temp_images/+the image.jpg try to log your file paths. And

File file = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), filename + ".jpg");

You have missed a /  between two paramaters.

[Wonderful blogpost about storing image](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/saving-loading-bitmaps-to-the-android-device-storage-internal-external/)

Comment: I tried putting **return file.getAbsolutePath()** but nothing

Comment: What you are getting ? Image saved to storage ?

Comment: Have you added the permissions?

Comment: I can't believe this: I added **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>** instead of **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>**
The code I had before was good