# Don't display Facebook app in Android Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

Hi I have the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
```

Now I can choose among a lot of applications: Gmail, Twitter, Facebook, SMS

But I don't want to display the Facebook option. Is this possible?

Or is it possible to add custom code when I click on the Facebook item? Like displaying an alertDialog etc

Comment: try to think in reverse, why would you application limit the user in their choice? if the user has installed the facebook application he will probably use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try send the url like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));  
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. use the `PackageManager` to resolve the intent,
2. get the list of candidate applications,
3. exclude Facebook from that list
4. create the activity picker yourself with this updated list

This would be the exact opposite of [Android Intent for Twitter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application/5291782#5291782)