# Send Message to specific user in twitter in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am getting the friend list from twitter now i want to tweet to particular user selected from the list. Any code snippet would  be appreciated. Here is i am getting `NullPointerException` on `twitter.sendmessage("id of user","msg")`

```
private void tweet(){
    setTitle("Tweet");
    AlertDialog.Builder inputDialog;
    inputDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    inputDialog.setTitle("Enter Tweet");
    et_input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    et_input.setWidth(250);
    et_input.setHeight(30);
    inputDialog.setView(et_input);
    inputDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txt_tweet= et_input.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("String what i have type "+txt_tweet);
            try{
               twitter.sendMessage("testsynapse1", txt_tweet);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Tweet Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (TwitterException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });
    inputDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancle",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    inputDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: `Any code snippet would be appericiated.` - likewise to you. Could you provide an outline of your current code?

Comment: Look here: [ask]. **1.** You'll give answerers an insight of your research so they don't have to do it themselves. If you ask without context, you should accept that you're only asking the few people who have done this recently and therefore remember it all, plus are willing provide the time and effort into providing an answer that will most likely be edited multiple times since you didn't provide in what context you want this to be implemented. **2.** If you provide code, people will be able to understand the problem faster, and they'll also be able to do their own research based on that.

Comment: AskeB thanx for u r kind info i m asking to who already implement like expertese on this subject

Comment: Well, I'm sure there's plenty of people here who are either willing to help you with a solution or have experience with the matter, after all it's not a new technology released today. What I'm saying is, you will most likely not be getting the answers you need if you ask this way.

Comment: Maybe this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application

Comment: What type is that `twitter`-variable you call the `sendMessage()`-method on? Is it [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org)? [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the username of particular user? If yes,

Then do like this:

```
String tweetToPost="@"+userName+"%20"+"your message"; 

postTweet(tweetToPost); 


public void postTweet(String str){
  String url="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+str.replace(" ","%20");

  WebView wv=new WebView(this);
        wv.loadUrl(url);
        setContentView(wv);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }


        });


}
```

I don't know if it works or not. But generally tweets to a specific user in Twitter are in the same format.

Comment: Can u eloborate on postTweet method

Comment: But i want to send without opening a webview

Comment: @arunjagga Which is an example of why you should have provided that, among other contexts, in your original question.

Comment: This is the simple method. If you don't want webview, go ahead using twitter api. Change the code in postTotweet method and use your own. There are plenty of examples which guide to post a tweet on twitter.

Comment: @AskeB if you dont know the answer Please leave let other understand it