# check to see if twitter app is present on user's device

Tags: android

In my project i want to connect my app with twitter. It will first check if twitter app is present on user's device if yes it will take credential from there only else this button will be disabled.

suggest me.

Comment: [Android Intent for Twitter application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2077008/593709)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this to check if the official Twitter application is installed:

```
PackageManager pkManager = activity.getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo pkgInfo = pkManager.getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
    String getPkgInfo = pkgInfo.toString();

    if (getPkgInfo.equals("com.twitter.android"))   {
        // APP NOT INSTALLED
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    // APP NOT INSTALLED

}
```

*However*, even if it is installed, you will not be able to pull out any credentials from it to use within your own app. You will need to the [Twitter4J library](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) to manage user authentication within your own app. Pulling out data from the app, if it were installed, is just **not an option**.

Comment: ohk. then can i start that app for authentication??

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj: Actually, the authentication will be done in a browser. It could be a `WebView` in your app or you could let the user choose a browser of his choice (_from among those installed on his device_) to complete the authentication process. But unlike the Facebook SSO, the Twitter app is not involved in this process.

Comment: Very helpful response, my use of this code is in the link below if useful to anyone: https://github.com/lararufflecoles/KittyCatImageGenerator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/es/rufflecol/lara/kittycatimagegenerator/MainActivity.java

Comment: @LaraRuffleColes: Thank you. Glad to have been of help. I did visit the GitHub link and would want to make a quick suggestion. Don't include, what I am assuming are, the real Twitter API Key and Secret in it. ;-)

Comment: I've thought about that thanks, decided it wasn't a big deal for my wee app. :-).

Answer (score 3):

```
try{
    ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
            getApplicationInfo("com.twitter.android", 0 );
    return true;
} catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    return false;
}
```

this will check if the official app for `Twitter` is installed or not

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean twitterInstalled = false;

    try{
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
                getApplicationInfo("com.twitter.android", 0 );
        twitterInstalled = true;
    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    }
```