# Share Text + URL on Twitter with Intent

Tags: android

Right now when I try to share, the URL is not recognized from Twitter and it displays only the text.

This is my code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setPackage(Constants.SOCIAL_TWITTER);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, testURL);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

context.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

I want the tweet to recognize the URL and display image from it as it normally does.

Comment: `intent.setType("image/*");` you tried this MIME type?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application or this https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose

Comment: This(setType("image/*") is also not working.

Comment: @FrankLucas, I've looked through these posts before posting the question